# Excel not detecting proper amount of cores

Tags: microsoft-excel, threads

Has anybody came across how to get excel to detect the proper amount of cores when on a high core count machine. I have a EPYC VM with 32 cores assigned, and Excel only detects 2 for some reason. When we manually assign Excel to use 32 cores it functions as expected, just that the end users have to manually set this.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're running in a virtual machine. Are you sure you gave the VM access to multiple cores ? It might be set to run on 1 (hyperthreaded) core and thats why excel only shows 2 available.

Comment: If you look at the Task Manager it shows 32 cores available. I don't think that Hyper-V can see the abstraction of being a HT thread or main core.